# Variables that best discriminate groups based on the glmnet package

Tags: r, feature-selection, glmnet, elastic-net

I am trying to understand how to interpret the result from the glmnet package. What I ultimately want to find is a set of (influential or important) variables that best discriminates three groups (e.g., low, med, high) using the elastic-net regression method.

There's the example code reproducible:

```
tempcv <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(iris[,-5]), y=iris[,5], family="multinomial", 
                    nfolds=20, alpha=0.5)
coefsMin <- coef(tempcv, s="lambda.min")
```

Then what I get is the following:

```
$setosa
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)  15.119192
Sepal.Length -1.897589
Sepal.Width   5.455627
Petal.Length -2.807969
Petal.Width  -5.942061

$versicolor
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)   4.795799
Sepal.Length  1.726752
Sepal.Width   .       
Petal.Length -1.160588
Petal.Width  -1.978123

$virginica
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept)  -19.914991
Sepal.Length   .       
Sepal.Width   -3.925362
Petal.Length   4.536932
Petal.Width    9.236506
```

In this case, using the absolute value of each coefficient, can I interpret this result as follows? 
***The two variables that best discriminate "setosa" from other two groups ("versicolor" and "virginica") are Sepal.Width (5.46) and Petal.Width (-5.94).***

If this is wrong, then how can I select some variables/features that best discriminate groups?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Could you explain how you came up with this interpretation?  In particular, why do you ignore the different intercepts?

Comment: Hi @whuber ! The interpretation just came up solely based on the magnitude of the coefficients. I ignored the intercepts, because the main and the only interest is to select two most important variables that can discriminate groups. If this is not the right answer, then do you perhaps know how I can select important features when it comes to multinomial glmnet?

Comment: The intercept sure looks like it can help distinguish these groups ;-).  Ordinarily, inspection of the estimates won't determine which variables "best" discriminate among groups.  You need further analysis.  All that `glmnet` is doing for you is to suggest variables that exhibit *detectable relationships* with group membership *in this dataset.* It's not performing any cluster analysis.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the reply! So... the variables with nonzero coefficients (e.g., sepal & pedal width) are the ones that exhibit detectable relationship with group membership? Could you plesae elaborate the "detectable relationship"? And also, in such case, does the magnitude of coefficient play no role in glmnet? It has to have some meaning... right?

Comment: @whuber For example, in case of the second block with "$versicolor", the coefficient of sepal width is 0, while pedal width has the coefficient with the highest magnitude. It means that the sepal width is not important, but pedal width is important in terms of membership predictive accuracy?

Comment: With "detectable relationship" I'm simply describing any kind of regression results.  In this case, *all* the variables exhibit detectable relationships: it suffices for a variable to appear in just one group for it to be useful to discriminate that group.  The magnitude of the coefficient needn't be at all related to usefulness for clustering/discrimination problems.

Comment: @whuber I think I am getting it. So the magnitude of the coefficient does not necessarily imply how important the variable is for discriminating the group from other two groups; but "all variables" with nonzero coefficients are useful in terms of membership predictive accuracy. Is it correct?

Comment: @whuber If so, suppose that there are 20 variables with nonzero coefficients. Because it is too large, I would like to (or should) report ONLY two important/influential variables that can discriminate Group 1 from other groups. Then glmnet CANNOT answer this question, right?

Comment: Right and right.  `glmnet` is, however, useful for suggesting variables to include in a follow-on cluster analysis.  You could even take the sizes of the coefficients as hints concerning which variables to look at most closely -- just don't assume that will necessarily get you the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for all your tremendous help, @whuber ! I have one final question (sorry for bothering you!). So does it sound reasonable if I then perform the multinomial regression only using the variables with nonzero coefficients (assuming that the data was standardized/normalized)? I believe that the coefficient then can play a role as a variable importance score. The reason of doing this is to select only a couple of important features that can best discriminate groups...

Comment: I believe that's precisely what `glmnet` has already done for you.  The issue is whether you want to trust the regularized (`glmnet`) estimate or the usual (GLM) estimate.  The former, although biased, tends to be better for prediction and latter--perhaps--better for *scientific explanations.*  Thus, both options are valid, depending on your objectives.  For clustering I suspect you might be in the first case.

Comment: @whuber Wait... Didn't you mention that the size/magnitude of coefficient from glmnet CANNOT indicate how important the variable is for discriminating the group from other two groups...?? That is, the variable with large coefficients does not necessarily imply that the variable is important (in terms of membership predictive accuracy) compared to variables. Doesn't it?
Then if I want to sort the variables with nonzero coefficients by their importance in terms of membership prediction accuracy, shouldn't I need to use other regression methods, other then using glmnet?

Comment: That is correct, which is why I called the magnitudes only "hints."  Under certain circumstances those hints might pan out, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Got it. I sincerely appreciate it, @whuber !!!!! :-)